# Removing Null items in php array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove `null` in the following php array?
Can anyone help me pease?

```
{
    "total": 20,
    "memberships": [
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-548a652109b5f855658713",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-5695f8e9a0c56329461106",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-540e028357c11975473911",
        "channel-5631e7c4a317d864607733",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-5631e7c4a317d864607733",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-548a652109b5f855658713",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-548a652109b5f855658713",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-548a652109b5f855658713",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568d788e05dcd282842479",
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-5695f8e9a0c56329461106",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "channel-568e2ec856e52816891757",
        "channel-5695f8e9a0c56329461106",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        [
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `array_filter`:

```
array_filter($array)
```

array_filter keeps any element evalueted as `true` in the array. It returns a new array.

Answer (score 2):

array_filter can remove empty strings, false values and null's from your array:

```
$entry = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => ''
          );

print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

Further more you can define your own filter and call array_filter with a callback function with your desired filtering:

```
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
```

will output:

```
Odd :
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 3
    [e] => 5
)
Even:
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [2] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [6] => 12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search recrusively and remove each element. Maybe some approach like this one (attention - I have not tested the code and I am NOT a php programmer):

```
function RemoveNull($array)
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      RemoveNull($value);
    }

    if ($value == null)
    {
      unset($array[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Modifying `$array` does not change the original array as arguments aren't passed in by values. In this case the array ought be either passed by reference or must be "referenced" by  `global` keywordin the function body.